# How do I use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, objective-c-blocks

I am having trouble in converting this Block code from Objective C into Swift. I searched the web found some examples but none fixed the errors I get.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [[self.viewControllersByIdentifier allKeys] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (![self.destinationIdentifier isEqualToString:key]) {
            [self.viewControllersByIdentifier removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
    }];
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    var array : NSArray = self.viewControllersByIdentifier.allKeys
    array.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (key, idx, stop) in
        if (![self.destinationIdentifier == key]) {
            self.viewControllersByIdentifier .removeObjectForKey(key)
        }
    }
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

And the error I am getting is on the "if" statement and it tells me that "String is not convertible to "MirrorDisposition".

Comment: What errors? What are you trying to do? What do you expect to happen, what is the actual result?

Comment: Rather than changing the whole question, you should have marked @AirspeedVelocity as 'answered' and asked another question.  Now, the question is unclear.

Comment: @GoZoner didn’t mean change your new question to better work, he meant restore the original text, mark this one as answered (assuming it was) and ask a brand new question.  Otherwise the answers below make no sense for anyone else who comes to read them (as they’re answering your old pre-edited question).

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Done!!! thanks!!! Will post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve left a bit of Objective-C in your Swift (some rogue square brackets):

```
if(![self.destinationIdentifier == key]) {
```

However, you would probably find it easier to use Swift’s for-in than `array.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`:

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    for key in self.viewControllersByIdentifier.allKeys {
        // note key will be an AnyObject so you need to cast it to an appropriate type… 
        // also, this means you can use != rather than ! and ==
        if self.destinationIdentifier != key as? NSString {
            self.viewControllersByIdentifier.removeObjectForKey(key)
        }
    }
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the documentation?

```
func enumerateObjectsUsingBlock(_ block: (AnyObject!,
                                     Int,
                                     UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

Comment: I did, I came to that code I edited my question, but still getting error.